# Timeago plugin is not working in iOS using ionic

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have working in mobile app for android and iOS, To display the time I have used timeago plugin, its working in android but the same code is not working in iOS. Please find below for my code.

```
//https://github.com/uttesh/ngtimeago
<div class="post-content" >{{ post.time|timeago }}</div>
```

The above code display the result `July 13, 2014 11:13:00` as `3 years ago`. I have searched for other plugins same as timeago for iOS.

Comment: what about `angular-moment`..? see https://github.com/urish/angular-moment

Comment: Thanks Edison, I have tried angular-moment, but i face an issue while implementing into the app,

Answer (score 0):

Instead I have used the below plugin,

https://github.com/yaru22/angular-timeago

It works fine in both android and iOS, By using this plugin i have fixed my issue. To change the time ("time: "2017-04-17 22:22:03") into timeAgo format("About 8 Hours").
Thanks